# Why am I getting the message “Single-stepping until exit from function shellcode which has no line number information” in GDB?

Tags: c, gdb, buffer, buffer-overflow

I tried to use **buffer overflow** to rewrite my function's return address,and it worked.but when i try to step through the function(stored in the char array),I get the message:

```
"Single stepping until exit from function shellcode, 
which has no line number information."
```

I've compiled my C program using gcc  using the flag -g，and i just have one file.
so here is my diffrence:i want to execute the function which is not "real code".It's stored in the char array ,looks like this:

```
char shellcode[]="\x31\xc0\xb0\x46\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc0"
                 "\x88\x43\x07\x89\x5b\x08\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d"
                 "\x53\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73"
                 "\x68";
```

My system is Kali linux, is this concern?
Here is debug session: [image]

this problem upset me very much,if someone can help,it would be very awesome!

Comment: but your function is pure binary data. Of course it has no line information... I think `si` is the instruction step you're looking for.

Comment: thank you for your comments, but i can't understand what is "si"，can you explain it any more?

Comment: step instruction command in gdb

Comment: thank you，i think i have mixed something,you are great,thank again!